# Add users to the group using SPServices?

Tags: jquery, groups, spservices

I created a button in sharepoint site using content Editor,when the current users click on the button he must have to add to that particular group,can any one give example how to add current users to group using SPServices?

Comment: Did you mean that there's a group that current user is not yet a member of (neither explicitly, nor via domain groups) and you want this button to allow the users to add themselves to the group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [AddUserToGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772683(v=office.12).aspx) operation for that purpose, for example:

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "AddUserToGroup",
    groupName: groupName,
    userLoginName: userLoginName,
    completefunc: function(data,status){
       //... 
    }
});
```

### References

[Managing SharePoint Site User Memberships in Multiple Groups Using SPServices](http://sympmarc.com/2011/11/03/managing-sharepoint-site-user-memberships-in-multiple-groups-using-spservices/)

Comment: Current user must have permission to join the group.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, SPServices or any other client-side development is not the way to go.

Better use out-of-the-box settings of the group to *allow any users to view membership* and *auto-accept requests for joining and leaving the group* if that's appropriate for the group.

Then simply provide a hyperlink to the group's page (.../_layouts/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=...) where an out-of-the-box button to **Join** will be available.